# Disable all but TLS 1.2 on HP JetDirect 635n network card

Tags: security, printer, https, network-printer, tls

I have the latest firmware update for the JetDirect 635n (J7961G), which is at v41.16 (2017). Unfortunately, I cannot seem to switch the web interface for this network card over to TLS 1.2. It seems to operate only on TLS 1.0, which is being removed out of web browsers in short order.

In particular, my Web Management interface doesn’t allow me the option for selecting which TLS version to allow:

[image: Screenshot of Mgmt Protocols - Web Management interface]

However in most documentation, this is exactly the place where it should be selectable.

I have this particular card in several different printers, including an HP 5000DTN and a few more 4050DTN machines. It is a very recent gigabit card, so it stands to reason it should have TLS 1.2 support; it’s not like it is a 10/100 card.

Comment: Tell us about the certificate for the printer itself.  How did you create it? [Background](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04746242#AbT2)

Comment: It is a self-signed 2048-bit cert, 5-year duration. Completely bog-standard. It’s what I can set up at the moment without shelling out $$$ to a CA, and is perfectly adequate for internal use. There are no other self-signed cert options other than duration or key length.

Comment: I assume [HP Web Jetadmin](https://h30670.www3.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=J6052AA) has been updated?

Comment: Not understanding why this has any relevance. The problem is with my JetDirect card, not with any secondary software which I haven’t needed across 18 years and four generations of JetDirect cards. The JetDirect card has a perfectly functional Web interface, the problem is that it isn’t switching over to TLS 1.2, despite being well modern enough (a gigabit card, latest 2017 firmware) to support it.

Comment: “to either upgrade an existing version of HP Web Jetadmin or install new on a Windows system.” - Yup, that’s gonna be a problem.

Comment: There are two places to set up a certificate: within the screen that I screenshotted, and within Authorization -> Certificates. Both do the same thing, and produce the same certificate via the same wizard. Neither provide any ability to modify TLS options.

Comment: Also, TLS 1.2 can be used with any ciphers defined for SSL 3.0 and later. This includes 3DES (DES-CBC3) ciphers (Appendix A.5, p75): https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt